# Know the font used in textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea, styling

I have a webpage, with a textarea and a text. 
I need to write a message(the text) in this web page in the same font and font-size as the one used in the textarea.

How can I know the name of the font and the size of the font used in the textarea?

For the people curious to know why I need this very font and font-size, it's because it is such that the width of any character and the width of a dash (-) are the same.

Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect which font a particular browser uses with some particular settings, but as an author, you cannot know which fonts will be used in each user’s browser.

To write a message in the same font as used in textarea elements by browser defaults, you can use a textarea element for it and just set its other properties suitably (e.g., making it readonly using the HTML attribute and making lines flow normally using `white-space: normal` in CSS).

But it seems that what you really want is a monospace font. In HTML, you can use just  for that. In CSS, you can set a list of fonts in preference order, e.g.

```
tt { font-family: Consolas, Courier New, monospace; }
```

Comment: OK. And can I set any font to be monospace? Or is there a restricted set of fonts that can give a monospace display ?

Comment: “Monospace” is a category of fonts: some fonts (such as Consolas and Courier New) are monospace, some aren’t; and the CSS keyword `monospace` refers to a browser-dependent default font. You can set the font of any element to a monospace font.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a bunch of such typefaces (fonts), called [monospace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). It's what you get when you specify `font-family:monospace` in your css rule, btw. )

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know about monospace.

Answer (score 1):

Use any HTML inspect tool like firebug (firefox addon) to know the properties used in your textarea.

Comment: Or in javascript, if you don't want to download firebug: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

Answer (score 0):

Use something like firebug (firefox addon), IE development tools or Chrome dev tools to find out the fonts used. Google "using firebug" you'll get tons of tutorials on how to use it. Hope this help

Comment: It did help, just installed, and spied on a website that had this feature ! Thanks !